# Anchor a page when a paragraph is expanded via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have a web page that dynamically creates comments.  Comments are minimized and can be expanded using the "more" link.  When I click the more link the page jumps to the top of the page.  I wanted to make it such that when the more button is clicked the full comment is shown and the page remains in the location of the comment.

HTML

```
<div tal:condition="not comment.pending_review">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${ comment.account.email }</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p class="more_text"
                                            style="width: 250px; white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis"
                                        >${ comment.comment }</p><a name="${ comment.id }" id="${ comment.id }" data-id="comment" class="more_link" href="#">more</a></td>
                                    <td><span class="star" tal:repeat="number [i for i in range( comment.star_rating )]">
                                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.more_link').click(function(){
               $('.more_text').css({'width': '', 'white-space': '', 'overflow': '', 'text-overflow': ''});
               $(this).hide();
               var anchor_id = $(this).attr('name');
               location.hash = "#" + anchor_id;
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you just use a **button** instead of an **a** ? You could delete the "href=#" part, which makes you jump to top then - Just a suggestion :)